# How to get a variable in a modal using datatable in laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, datatables

I am using yajra datatables in laravel and I have the "revisar" button that shows a modal (as shown in the following image):

[modal show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMwaM.png)

I want to fill this textarea with information from the "detail" field of the database that is obviously different for each item of the datatable, how would you do to obtain that data? I thought about getting it from the variable of the partials.actions which I can send from the controller of the datatable, but I can't get that variable in blade view.

my partials.actios view:

```
<a href="{{ route('tareas.createfrom', Hashids::encode($id)) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-plus"></i>
    Tarea
</a>
<a href="{{ route('solicituds.show', Hashids::encode($id)) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">
    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-eye"></i>
    Ver
</a>
<button type="button" data-id="{{ $id }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#RevisaSolicitudModal" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm revisar" id="getActualizaId">
    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-check-circle"></i>
    Revisar
</button>
<button type="button" data-id="{{ $id }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DeleteProductModal" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="getDeleteId">
    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-trash"></i>
    Eliminar
</button>
```

Maybe I can get the variable "$detail" in the modal using JS, I don't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check bootstrap documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/#varying-modal-content

```
<button type="button" data-id="{{ $id }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#RevisaSolicitudModal" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm revisar" id="getActualizaId">
    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-check-circle"></i>
    Revisar
</button>
```

...

```
<script>
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var id = button.data('id') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  ...
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My Approach which worked:

1.Controller:

```
          return \Yajra\DataTables\DataTables::of($trxDatatables)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                    
                    $stEditRoute = route('admission.students.edit',$row->id);
                    $stShowRoute = route('admission.students.show',$row->id);
                    $btns = '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs
                              deleteModalTriggerBtn " id="deleteModalTriggerBtn"  
                              data-catid='.$row->id.' data-toggle="modal"
                              data-target="#delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" title="Delete Center"/></button>';
                    return $btns;
                })
                ->rawColumns(['action'])
                ->toJson();
```

2. Jquery:

   ```
    $(document).ready(function () {

      // used the following technique so that I can use the custom attribute (data-catid)  value of the trigger button (id="delete") when delete ajax is called.

      $(function() {

          var stId = null;
          function getCatId() {
              $('#delete').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
                  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
                  var id = button.data('catid'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
                  stId = id;

              });

          }

          getCatId();



      $('.modal-footer').on('click', '.delete', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");

          var reason = $("#reason option:selected").text();
          var notice = $("#notice").val();
          $.ajax({
              type: 'DELETE',
              url: 'http://yoursite.test/workplace/admission/students/'+stId,
              data: {
                  'id': stId,
                  'reason': reason,
                  'notice': notice,
                  "_token": token,
              },
              success: function (data) {

                  // console.log(data);
                  // $('.item' + $('.id').text()).remove();
              }
          });
      });

      });

        });
   ```